# Identify these two fonts, on serif one sans-serif

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif, serif

Please someone can helpme to identify these two fonts?

[image]
[image]

I have tried many different websites without success.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a [collection of font identification resources](http://www.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases.

Comment: So you have tried using http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ ? The `Gingko Biloba` one does show some results, however, the other one is too low res to be of recognised. Could you explain how the results from the many different websites are not helpful to you?

Comment: The typefaces are fairly obvious without using identification aids, so it would be really useful to know exactly what you have tried. WhatTheFont and Identifont do usually produce good results.

Comment: There's something fishy about that serif… It appears to be brutally condensed by a shear horizontal scaling (notice especially the dots over the “i”s). That may fool some “font finders” :}

Comment: @thebodzio Yes. "Brutally condensed" certainly. But it's TNR. *Capsules* is almost certainly [Helvetica Condensed Bold](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFont&code=HELA70012000).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oh, right! Well… like I said: “something fishy”… ;}

Answer (score 1):

None of these are exact matches, but they are close to the "CAPSULES" one.

**Korolev Heavy**

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/device/korolev/heavy/

Too wide. The P is off

**Helvetica Inserat**

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica-inserat/

The A seems to be off, but that might be because of the low resolution of the image

**Gothic No. 13**

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/gothic-no-13/

Again, the A seems to be off.

[image]